# Create new site with REST API

Tags: java, web-services, rest, alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to create a new site in Alfresco through the REST API first i tried with the url */alfresco/service/api/sites* the site was created but i could not open it. I read the method description and it says

> Note: this method only creates a site at the repository level, it
>   does not create a fully functional site.   It should be considered for
>   internal use only at the moment.   Currently, creating a site
>   programmatically needs to be done in the Share context, using the
>   create-site module.   Further information can be found at the address
>   http://your_domain:8080/share/page/index/uri/modules/create-site.post 
>   within your Alfresco installation.

I tried to go to the suggested url but it gives 404 ! 
Any help or suggestions ?

Comment: Did you replace `your_domain` with your installation's domain name?

Answer (score 2):

Note - the links/references in this answer all assume you've got the Alfresco Share application installed and available at `http://localhost:8081/share/` - tweak as needed for your machine

When wanting to understand or discover webscripts, the first place you want to head to is `http://localhost:8081/share/service/index` - the Share WebScripts home. (The Alfresco repo tier has an equivalent one too, available at a similar URL).

When there, you'll see all of the Share-side WebScripts listed, of which there are a lot. You could search through that list for `create-site`. However, you can restrict the webscript listing by URL or by module. For the Create Site webscripts, the URL to see just those is `http://localhost:8081/share/page/index/uri/modules/create-site`

Head there, and you'll discover there are two create site related webscripts, a get and a post. As you've discovered already, the one you'll want is the POST webscript. Click on that to get the details, at `http://localhost:8081/share/page/script/org/alfresco/modules/create-site.post` - that's the latest (Alfresco 5.x) URL for the thing you've been directed to in your question. If your Share installation is at a different URL, then once you've navigated from the Share webscripts home, you'll get the specific one for your machine

Finally, you'd need to post the required JSON to that webscript's URI, which is given in the webscript listing, eg `http://localhost:8081/share/page/modules/create-site` . Easiest way to see exactly what JSON you need is to use firebug / developer tools / etc to see the handful of keys/values that Share sends when you create one through the UI.

Comment: Thank you for help. the /share/page/modules/create-site requires user level authentication. so if i post a request it answers with 401 unauthorized. Any idea how add authetication parameters to the request ?

Comment: Get a ticket and pop that on the URL? Do a login request and get a cookie and include that?

Comment: I added the ticket from the login request to the create-site request but still have 401. Can you provide any more detailed resource/example supporting Alfresco 5.x ?